# What the difference between Debug and Release in ScriptManagers's ScriptMode?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

In *ASP.NET AJAX*, I can set `ScriptMode` for `ScriptManager`. 
The *script mode* can be *Debug* or *Release*.
What are the exact differences between them? Is it true that on *debug mode*, generated scripts won't cache on the browser while in *Release* mode they will be cached, and subsequent server access will be prevented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refering to [ScriptManager.ScriptMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.scriptmode.aspx):

> In *Debug* mode, debug versions of
>   client script libraries are used in
>   the Web page unless the retail
>   attribute of the deployment
>   configuration element is set to true.
>
> In *Release* mode, release versions of
>   client script libraries are used in
>   the Web page unless the retail
>   attribute of the deployment
>   configuration element is set to false.

Refering to [Debugging and Tracing Ajax Applications Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398817.aspx):

> The Microsoft Ajax architecture
>   provides a model for release and debug
>   modes. Release mode provides error
>   checking and exception handling that
>   is optimized for performance, with
>   minimized script size. Debug mode
>   provides more robust debugging
>   features, such as type and argument
>   checking. If you create debug versions
>   of client script files or script
>   resources, ASP.NET runs the debug
>   versions when the application is in
>   debug mode. This enables you to throw
>   exceptions in debug scripts but still
>   keep the size of release code to a
>   minimum.

Answer (score 0):

In release mode the ScriptManager will load the smaller, minified and unreadable JavaScript libraries. The debug version will load the actual source code with comments and good formatting but it will be slower because of the bigger size. Not that the ScriptManager will not automatically minify libraries that are not part of MS AJAX.